# Window Service and C# design pattern question

Tags: c#, design-patterns, windows-services, coding-style

I have recently taken over a legacy windows service and it has been writing the following event in the system event log:

> Event ID: 7034 
> Description: The
>   MyService service terminated
>   unexpectedly.  It has done this X
>   time(s).

I was looking over source code and found the following code pattern in the service class library:
(It has been simplified to protect the innocent..)

```
public static void StartService()
{
    //do some stuff...
    ManageCycle();
}

public static void ManageCycle()
{
   //do some stuff
   ManageCycle();
}
```

What is this coding patten called and could it possibly cause the windows service to shutdown (i.e. memory leak)?

Comment: OH-MY-GOD!!! why use recursive calling instead of while loop?!

Comment: Voting to close as "belongs on thedailywtf.com"

Answer (score 3):

It suppose to throw StackOverflow (HA HA :) ) Exception, because of the endless recursive calling.

Take a look at [this example](http://en.csharp-online.net/Creating_a_.NET_Windows_Service%E2%80%94Alternative_1:_Use_a_Separate_Thread) - you should choose the technique that fits your architecture.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the stack overflow exception pattern. Eran is correct. Use a while loop:

```
public static void StartService()
{
    //do some stuff...
    isRunning = true;
    ManageCycle();
}

public static void ManageCycle()
{
   while(isRunning)
   {
   //do some stuff and wrap in exception handling
   }
}

public static void StopService()
{
    isRunning=false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a recursive call that will ultimately blow the stack.

Comment: ...unless it has a conditional exit that we are not seeing.

Comment: @Michael: It doesn't matter, this is not a place for a recursive calling technique.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer for this kind of situation:
Don't use Recursive Algorithms unless your algorithm has a recursive structure. For example, if you're analyzing a file system, and want to scan a specific Directory, you'd want to do something like:

```
void ScanDirectory(Directory)
{
    // Handle Files
    if (currfile.directory)
        ScanDirectory(currfile)
}
```

This makes sense because it's much easier than doing it iteratively. But otherwise, when you're just repeating an action over and over again, making it a recursion is completely unnecessary and will cause code inefficiency and eventually stack overflows.

Comment: +1 This is the right conclusion for this question. It's more of a "how to code right?" question than "how to achieve code perfection?" question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive call with apparently no exit criteria.  Eventually it will run out of stack since a call to `ManageCycle` never returns.

In addition the StartService method will never return, it ought to be spining up at least one foreground thread and then return.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion, it ooks like it's recursively calling itself.  I'm surprised there isn't a stack overflow exception.  Perhaps the service property on the machine running this is configured to restart the service on failure.

Answer (score 0):

It's recursive alright. It will keep calling itself repeatedly (a bad thing) and that will result in a stackoverflow.

What the "//do some stuff" do? Maybe there is a good reason that it calls itself,
bBut without a way to get out of the loop (recursive), the application will exit.

Comment: the //do some stuff piece of the service call a database to retrieve a collection of monitors to check the health of web pages, windows services, hard drive capacity and whethor or not a device is pingable.